# Is it possible to display an image from an ftp folder into a gridview imagefield?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to display images in a imagefield from an ftp url? this is the code

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlFormatString="ftp://anonymous@192.168.1.37/{0}" DataImageUrlField="Imagen">
```

The gridview won't display the image and the ftp has open authentication